# Searching using inArray

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery inArray to search for a element with an associative array. What am I doing wrong in the below code ? It returns -1..

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hwSuD/1/

```
var arr = [];

arr[3435345] = {
    location : 'Earth'
}

console.log($.inArray(3435345,arr));  //throws -1
```

Comment: `$.inArray` searches for values, not keys.

Comment: This is *NOT* an "associative array".  Those do not exist in JavaScript!  There are numeric arrays (`[]`) and objects (`{}`).  I'd suggest an object here.  Doing `arr[3435345]` with an array, will add indexes 0 - 3435344 to the array too (as `undefined`)!  You should do this: `var obj = {}; obj[3435345] = {location : 'Earth'}; console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(3435345));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.inArray()` usage would look for `3435345` inside the array and return the index. You're adding an object to the 3435345 index of that array. This is how you'd use `$.inArray()`.

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(3435345);
var index = $.inArray(3435345, arr);
```

which would return 0.

You may want to be creating a hash table? In that case do this.

```
var obj = {};
obj[3435345] = { location: 'Earth' };
if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(3435345) ) {
  // It exists!
}
```